# Is it possible to pass an additional parameter with an onChange event in React functional approach

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I want to do something like,

```
<Input onChange={(e,myExtraParameter) => enteredData}/>
```

and then writing my onChange like,

```
enteredData = (e :React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement> | React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>,myExtraParameter : string ) => {
    console.log("extra parameter = " , myExtraParameter);

}
```

That is, I want to check my key pressed input and also do something with it using an extra parameter.

I checked resources which says well about passing such option in React class-based approach where I can use "this" pointer. But how to do it in React functional component functional approach ?

Comment: Typically it'd be something like `onChange={e => myFunction(e, extraParameter)}` where you proxy the event object to your callback and add in any other number of arguments. What is your *actual* code you are trying to use?

Comment: No, the handler is called by React. You can pass the event on to *your* function, though. Or you can wrap the component and provide your own `onChange` handler if it's something you need to do throughout your app.

Comment: @DrewReese ...yes that's a great help.

Comment: It isn't really any different passing a callback as prop in class-based vs functional components. The props *are* the *API*, i.e. the *interface* of the component, and this is agnostic of actual component implementation. A react component is a react component is a react component.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass any value as long the function that receives it allows it otherwise wont get it.

example.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={(event) => readName(event, "Miss")} />
```

Now the function

```
const readName = (event, gender) => {
  const { target: { value } } = event;
  console.log(value,gender);
}
```